# What would this character gain by killing Kat?

Tags: tenet

At the end of the movie *Tenet (2020)*, Priya tries to assassinate Kat but Protagonist saves her. What's the benefit for Priya if she succeeds in killing Kat?

Comment: Doesn't she say: *I have to tie up the loose ends* ? Maybe that's why

Answer (score 1):

Any person who knows where the "algorithm" is, or who may be holding pieces of it, is a risk of this information reaching the future antagonists: Either directly (person grows older, meets antagonists, blabs somehow); indirectly via talking to others, writing a journal, sending email etc.; or perhaps - another agent of the antagonists somehow gets to the person.

Thus - it is useful to just kill people with such information; that ends their potential for disclosing it.